# I don't want to run a function, just use it as a parameter, but it keeps popping

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I have read in other answers that in order to use a function as a parameter, it needs to be written `whatever;`and not `whatever()`because this las option "calls" the function. But what if I need to specify a parameter of said function? I give an example:

I have this function to replace some content:

```
function navigate(content) {
var card = document.getElementById('informationdiv');
card.innerHTML = content;
}
```

And then I have another function that creates the content:

```
function productsheet(article) {
    document.write(array_products[article].Name);
    document.write(array_products[article].Number);
    document.write(array_products[article].Type);
    // and so on...
```

Then, I want to call the first function like this:

```
navigate(productsheet(article));
```

And instead of do the innerHTML replacement, it just runs `productsheet(article)`overriding everything else.

As I said, I found similar problems where the solution was to pass `productsheet`without `(article)`, but in my case I need the article parameter, so `productsheet`knows what to print...

What is the suggested approach here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Suggested approach: remove the blight that is `document.write` from your code. If a function *does* stuff instead of *returning* stuff then it's not composable no matter how you slice it.

Comment: "it just runs productsheet(article)overriding everything else." That's the way `document.write()` works. When it is invoked after the page has been parsed, it automatically calls `document.open()`, which wipes out ALL your previous code and HTML.

Comment: I am using `document.write()`because in the rest of the function there is some code to draw an HTML table too... which by the way, I could consider doing with divs instead. But then again, to put divs in a .js document I know no other system than `document.write()`. There might be a more advanced solution, but I am in the very very beginner level at the moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are much better ways to achieve what you want, but taking your code as starting point I would do as follows:

```
navigate(article);

function navigate(article) {
    var card = document.getElementById('informationdiv');
    card.innerHTML = productsheet(article);
}

function productsheet(article) {
    //here you would return a string that has the format as how you would like to display it
    return "... name, number, type ...";
}
```

Again, I think you should rethink the whole approach and throw this code away.

Comment: Your suggestion was about to work, but it didn't, because deeper problems with my previous code, so I will take your last sentence and that's what I will do: rethink again.

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood your question correctly, you need to pass an anonymous function to `navigate` and call your `productsheet` function within that:

```
navigate(function () {
    productsheet(article);
});
```

However, I'm not really sure what you're trying to acheive... you probably want to get rid of those `document.write` calls and return a string from `productsheet`, and call the function instead of assigning a reference to it to `innerHTML`:

```
card.innerHTML = content();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion, and instead of replacing the content with what the function outputs, it replaces it by just the name of the function: the line `function () { productsheet(article);});